Stylex, React, Typescript and Vite project setup
I am trying to include Stylex in my vite project that is build with react and typescript and I keep stumbling in errors. For example:

The newest version of stylex and vite-plugin-stylex are not compatible.
After downgrading @stylexjs/stylex from 0.6.1 to 0.5.1 in order to have a compatible version with the plugin, when I try to import the plugin in vite.config.ts the plugin throws an error.

The error:
Cannot find module 'vite-plugin-stylex' or its corresponding type declarations.
  There are types at '/run/media/andre/Kingston/dev-setup/Babylon/babylon-ui-app/node_modules/vite-plugin-stylex/dist/index.d.mts', but this result could not be resolved under your current 'moduleResolution' setting. Consider updating to 'node16', 'nodenext', or 'bundler'

I want to mention that I tried all the moduleResolution specified and none worked.
Here is my vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import stylex from 'vite-plugin-stylex';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), stylex()],
});

@stylexjs/stylex:0.5.1
vite-plugin-stylex:0.8.3
More over, the build of the project fails to load the stylex styles.
If anyone managed to setup a project with vite, react, typescript and stylex, please share the setup so I can try it.
UPDATE 1: Adding tsconfig

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["src/components"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@widgets": ["src/widgets"],
      "@widgets/*": ["src/widgets/*"],
      "@config": ["src/config"],
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@dto": ["src/dto"],
      "@dto/*": ["src/dto/*"],
      "@hooks": ["src/hooks"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@redux": ["src/redux"],
      "@redux/*": ["src/redux/*"],
      "@socket": ["src/socket"],
      "@socket/*": ["src/socket"],
      "@types": ["src/types"],
      "@types/*": ["src/types"],
      "@utils": ["src/utils"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils*"]
    },
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}


UPDATE 2:
tsconfig.node.json is the file that needs an update. The module and moduleResolution should be set to nodenext.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}


Still, this does not solve the problem with the build. Once the project is built, the styles are not saved at all.
Is it maybe to early to consider vite and stylex?

Adding your current tsconfig.json to the question may help solving the problem
